# How to get access to Basecamp user detail using OAuth 2.0

Tags: asp.net-mvc, basecamp

I'm trying to get login using base camp as MVC project gives use Google facebook etc how can I get log in using my basecamp credentials

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of ways to implement that but the old is gold use **BasecampRestAPI** Its very easy to implement 
for example: Lets first authenticate the user

```
 public static bool Authenticate(string username, string password)
{


        BaseCamp objCamp = BaseCamp.GetInstance("https://CompanyName.basecamp.com", username, password);

        // as we authenticated, therefore pass username after formatting it i.e. converting "Khawaja.Atteeq" to "Khawaja Atteeq" format
        string user = username.Split('@')[0].Replace('.', ' ');
        user = new CultureInfo("en").TextInfo.ToTitleCase(user.ToLower());

        //  session if necessary.
        HttpContext.Current.Session["UserID"] = user;
        return true;
    }
```

Now lets go to the login page

```
 protected void SignIn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Authenticate(Username.Text.Trim(), Password.Text))
    {
        Response.Redirect("~/");
    }
    else
    {
        Error.Visible = true;
    }
}
```

Thats It Hope This helps